# Cannot cast object 'org.gradle.api.internal... after Update Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

after update the android studio to  version **3.3 Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772**, built on December 25, 2018 I began to receive this error message while trying to build my project:

**Cannot cast object 'org.gradle.api.internal.collections.SortedSetElementSource@4a6a22ae' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.collections.SortedSetElementSource' to class 'java.util.TreeSet'**. I've tried to fix it by myself but no success so far.

I've already tried:

**Clean project**
**Rebuild Project**
**Invalidate caches**

**more info:**
Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

any help would be apreciated.

Comment: If you create a new project via the new-project wizard, does the new project result in the same error?

Comment: No. Creating a new project works fine. I begging to think that this error is being caused by the gradle update that AS ask me to make after the IDE update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following recovery steps (which assume a fairly standard Android Studio project setup):

1. In Android Studio, choose File > Close Project in every open IDE window, until you get back to the welcome dialog
2. Make a backup of your entire project directory, in case these instructions do not work, so you can get back to your current state
3. In the project root directory, delete the `.gradle/`, `.idea/`, and `build/` subdirectories, along with any `*.iml` files
4. In each module directory (e.g., `app/`), delete the `build/` subdirectory, along with any `*.iml` files
5. In the welcome dialog, choose "Import project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)"
6. Choose your project directory and click OK to import it

This is basically a "deep clean" of the project, getting rid of *everything* that is not part of the actual project source code. With luck, your project will now work successfully.

If *that* fails, start comparing the Gradle files from this project and a newly-created project (which, in your comments, seems to work OK), and try to work out which of the differences is causing your problem.